# Dirichlet integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

As the title suggests, I'm supposed to calculate the Dirichlet integral using complex analysis. To do this I've been given a list of steps I'm supposed to complete. Sadly I'm already having a hard time understanding the very first one. They define the contour:
$$\gamma_R(t)=   
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}  
t, & t \in [-R,R]\setminus[-1,1] \\  
-i \exp(\frac {\pi}2 it), & t  \in ]-1,1[  
\end{array} \right.$$
For $R>1$. Given this contour, I should be able to show, that:
$$\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{\sin(z)}z dz =\int_{-R}^R \frac{\sin(x)}x dx$$
How does one go about proving this? I'm having a hard time understanding why the equality holds and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What do you get if you plug in the definition of $\gamma_R$ into the left. Integral?

Comment: the $\gamma _R$ is not a contour, its just a path from $-R$ to $R$. The equality follows due to the Cauchy integral theorem as if you add a path that is a straight line from $R$ to $-R$ to $\gamma _R$ then you have a contour (a closed path) and the integrand is holomorphic (so the integral in this contour is zero)

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for the comment. I'm assuming, that I'm allowed to use the Cauchy integral theorem, since the integrand has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Is that correct?

Comment: The first step is just the equality $$\int\limits_{-1}^1{\sin x\over x}\,dx = \int\limits_{|z|=1,{\rm Im}\,z\le 0}{\sin z\over z}\,dz$$

Comment: @Francesco yes, the integrand is holomorphic, so the Cauchy integral theorem applies to any chosen closed path in $\mathbb{C}$